# Codeigniter connection to remote PostgreSql database

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I hope someone can help. I am running `codeigniter 3.05` and trying to connect to a remote `PostgreSql` database. If I set session to database, I get `include(.../views/errors/html/error_php.php) failed to open stream`  error message.

No other session configuration setting generates the error. If I run a method on a model, I get the same error along with: `Fatal error: Call to a member function from() on null in /opt/share/php/ci/application/libraries/ActiveRecord.php on line 295.`

I run the `PostgreSql` client from `command line` and I can connect to the database ok. I am running `Ubuntu 15.04` and I have checked permissions and ownership settings for `Codeigniter`. I had a similar problem loading the model, but, when I changed the first letter of the name of the file to uppercase, the message disappeared.

Is there a database driver that I need to change the first letter so `Ubuntu` can find it? Or, what else could it be?

Comment: Have you setup the database connect string in `/config/database.php` and enabled the database library in your controller (manually or by means of autoload) ?

Comment: Yes I reviewed the settings. They were correct.